# Fire event with repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using a Repeater, there is a button for each item. When I click on one of these buttons asp.net returns me the following error:

```
Invalid postback or callback argument
```

But when I add the Page directive EnableEventValidation = "false" on my page, no error but does not fire my event.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["user"] != null)
    {
        Customer activeCustomer = (Customer)Session["user"];
        Response.Write("Welcome " + activeCustomer.FirstName + " " + activeCustomer.LastName + " | Offer count:" + activeCustomer.OfferLimit);
        if (!IsPostBack)
         {
             ProdRepeater.DataSource = CampaignDataProcess.getDailyCampaign();
             ProdRepeater.DataBind();
         }
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
    }
}
```

I have already tried `if(!IsPostBack)` in page load.

How can this be resolved?

Comment: `!IsPostBack` should have solved it. Can you please post come code of how you tried that, maybe there is some problem in there?

Comment: Are you using UpdatePanel? Your button is subscribing to `OnCommand` or `OnClick`?

Comment: @rodrigogq yes it is a kind of UpdatePanel.Button is subscribing to OnCommand

Comment: Make sure you are not changing anything outside your update panel that should reflect in your list and you forget to update your list. Example: You change a checkbox outside the update panel that changes an item in your list without rebinding it.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using more than form in your aspx file, you can not use your events. I had a problem like your and i solved my problem deleting that form tags.

Comment: if using more than one form is illegal than why there is a property called id.@Yusuf